# Can't get actvity to navigate to another activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I've got 2 activities that stores/get data from firebase, different data but they are related to each other.

The first activity stores for example different food dishes in a listview, and when I click on one of the items I get to the second activity where I can store different things under the first item i chose in my first activity. So for example, if I click on "PIZZA" I get to a new activity where I can store "Italian Pizza". And this is working fine. But I want to have a middle activity that will appear after my first activity, and in this middle activity I want to have a button that gets me to my second activity.

So between the first and second activity it is no problem, works like a charm. But when I try to use this middle activity with a button, it doesn't work. I guess it has to have something to do with the middle activity, that it is not "connected" with the database for the other activities. But I don't know, need help :)

I get this error when trying to click on the add button:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source:40)
```

First Activity:

```
public class Jobbliste extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseJobber;

    public static final String jobbnavn = "jobbnavn";
    public static final String jobbId = "jobbid";


    TextView jobbliste
    ListView listjobber;
    ImageView leggtiljobb;

    List<Jobber> listjobb;

    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jobbliste);

        databaseJobber = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobber");
        databaseVerktøy = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Verktøy");
        databaseAnsatt = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ansatte");


        jobbliste = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjobbliste);
        listjobber = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvjobbliste);

        listjobber.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                Jobber jobber = listjobb.get(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(jobbId, jobber.getJobbId());
                intent.putExtra(jobbnavn, jobber.getJobbnavn());

                startActivity(intent);

                return false;


            }
        });


        leggtiljobb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tvleggtiljobb);

        listjobb = new ArrayList<>();
        søkjobb = new ArrayList<>();

        leggtiljobb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent leggtil = new Intent(Jobbliste.this, Leggtiljobb.class);
                startActivity(leggtil);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseJobber.orderByChild("jobbnavn").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                listjobb.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot jobberSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    final Jobber jobber = jobberSnapshot.getValue(Jobber.class);

                    listjobb.add(jobber);

                    final listJobber adapter = new listJobber(Jobbliste.this, listjobb);
                    listjobber.setAdapter(adapter);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class Notater extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String jobbnavn = "jobbnavn";
    public static final String jobbId = "jobbid";


    TextView tvjobbnavn;
    EditText etnotater;
    Button btnlagrenotat;
    ListView lvnotater;
    Button btntest;
    TextView tvjobbnavn1;

    DatabaseReference databaseNotater;
    DatabaseReference databaseJobber;

    List<Notat> notater;
    List<Jobber> listjobb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notater);


        tvjobbnavn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjobbnavn);
        tvjobbnavn1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvjobbnavn1);

        etnotater = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnotater);
        btnlagrenotat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlagrenotat);
        lvnotater = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvnotater);
        btntest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntest);
        lvnotater.setItemsCanFocus(true);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        notater = new ArrayList<>();
        listjobb = new ArrayList<>();


        String id = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbId);
        String navn = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbnavn);

        tvjobbnavn.setText(navn);


        databaseNotater = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notater").child(id);
        databaseJobber = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobber").child(id);


        btnlagrenotat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lagrenotat();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseNotater.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                notater.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot notatsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Notat notat = notatsnapshot.getValue(Notat.class);
                    notater.add(notat);


                }
                listNotater notatlistadapter = new listNotater(Notater.this, notater);

                lvnotater.setAdapter(notatlistadapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void lagrenotat() {
        String notatavn = etnotater.getText().toString().trim();


        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(notatavn)) {
            String id = databaseNotater.push().getKey();

            Notat notat = new Notat(id, notatavn);
            databaseNotater.child(id).setValue(notat);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Skriv noe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

My middle Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String jobbnavn = "jobbnavn";
    public static final String jobbId = "jobbid";

    Button add;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        Intent intent = getIntent();


        String id = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbId);
        String navn = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbnavn);

        text.setText(navn);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent leggtil = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notater.class);
                startActivity(leggtil);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So "Jobbliste" is your first Activity and you want to get to "MainActivity" and finally to "Notater"? I'm asking because I can't find the part in the first Activity where you start the middle Activity

Comment: Yes that's right. I edited the code now. What happens is, I get to "MainActivity" from "Jobbliste", but not from "MainActivity"  to "Notater". But it works from "Jobbliste" to  "Notater" without problems.

Comment: You mean you click the "add" Button in MainActivity and nothing happens? Or you click the "add" Button and the app crashes?

Comment: The app crashes, and I get this error: **  java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source:40)**

Comment: Add the error to the question, don't add it as a comment. Comments have basically no formatting, or newlines. Also, why do you have a couple of detached brackets in the first activity, right after `listjobb`?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to put the Intent extras (*id* and *navn*) when starting the second Activity from MainActivity

Comment: Can you show me that in my code? @0X0nosugar

Comment: I've tried to do the same as I have done in my OnItemclicklistener, but this line does not work `Jobber jobber = listjobb.get(i);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's compare how you start `Notater`

From `Jobbliste` in your first, working version:

```
listjobber.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Jobber jobber = listjobb.get(i);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(jobbId, jobber.getJobbId());
        intent.putExtra(jobbnavn, jobber.getJobbnavn());
        startActivity(intent);

        return false;
    }
});
```

From `MainActivity`:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent leggtil = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notater.class);
            startActivity(leggtil);
        }
    });
```

In `Notater`, you try to get the values for *id* and *navn*, but right now the `Intent` which was used to start `Notater` does not have any extras so both variables are `null`. This causes the `NullPointerException`.

There are two lines missing right before `startActivity()`:

```
leggtil.putExtra(Jobbliste.jobbId, id);
leggtil.putExtra(Jobbliste.jobbnavn, navn);
```

(Please note that in order to be able to access the `String` variables *id* and *navn* from `onClick()`, you have to make them `final`.)

Comment: This worked, thank you very much :) But it did work without making them `final`. Have I done something wrong then? Now I manage to navigate to `Notater` from `MainActivity`, but when I try to save new data from `Notater` to my listview (firebase) it does'nt relate it to the `Jobbliste`, only add a new data in firebase with no relation. Why is that`?

Comment: @Alexander - "But it did work without making them final." Well, my Android Studio always complains when I try to access local variables from an OnClickListener method. Maybe because without making them final one can't be exactly sure about the value at execution time? And about the firebase problem: I don't have any experience with firebase, so you'd best ask a new question about this new issue.

Comment: But maybe your issue can be solved if you refresh the ListView content in `onResume()` ?

Comment: Maybe I should make them final then. But anyways, you saved my day :) @0X0nosugar